# how to get full path of file in dropbox in swift programatically

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to display an image from dropbox item in imageview, for which I want complete path to that image item so that I can get image from nsdata of theat url.

Following is the code I am using:

```
 client.files.getMetadata(path: "/hello.txt").response { response, error in
                    print("*** Get file metadata ***")
                    if let metadata = response {
                        if let file = metadata as? Files.FileMetadata {
                            print("This is a file with path: \(file.pathLower)")
                            print("File size: \(file.size)")
                        } else if let folder = metadata as? Files.FolderMetadata {
                            print("This is a folder with path: \(folder.pathLower)")
                        }
                    } else {
                        print(error!)
                    }
```

Here file.pathLower returns relative path and not full path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display an image from Dropbox, you'll first need to download it. Search for "download a file" in the [Swift tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/swift#tutorial).